# Extract value of JavaScript variable using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I try to extract using

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
System.out.println(js.executeScript("return myArray;"));
```

I get exception

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: myArray is not
>   defined

`myArray` is a JavaScript variable that is populated by an ajax call.

Please help

Comment: I recommend that you use something like Firebug on your website to see if you can come up with a javascript command that will return what you are looking for.  It may be that you first need to use Selenium to drive the browser to the state that myArray has been defined and populated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much familiarity with selenium, but looks like 'myArray' is not found into context due to some error. It is not initialized, which might be due to an error in the Ajax call.

Comment: its not an error in ajax call. but maybe because the scope of the myArray is not global.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this. It may solve your problem.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
System.out.println(js.executeScript("return myArray"));
```